# Accessing variable from class in different module

Tags: python, python-3.x, pyqt, pyqt5

Trying to create a separate module for a function that saves the QLineEdit widgets text into a text file, I am having issues trying to access another modules variables that are inside a class and a function.

Module i'm creating:

```
import VlS
VS = VlS.Ui_VlS().setupUi()
class SaveInput:
    def SaveText (self):
        SavedText = open('Saved_Input.txt', 'w')
        SavedText.write('Stag#' + '-' + VS.Stag.text() + '\n')
```

Imported Module:

```
class Ui_VlS(object):
    def setupUi(self, VlS):
        VlS.setObjectName("Value")
        self.scrollAreaWidgetContents = QtWidgets.QWidget()
        self.scrollAreaWidgetContents.setGeometry(QtCore.QRect(0, 0, 1006, 1283))
        self.scrollAreaWidgetContents.setObjectName("scrollArea")
        self.gridLayout_2 = QtWidgets.QGridLayout(self.scrollAreaWidgetContents)
        self.gridLayout_2.setContentsMargins(0, 0, 0, 0)
        self.gridLayout_2.setObjectName("gridLayout_2")
        self.Stag = QtWidgets.QLineEdit(self.scrollAreaWidgetContents)
        sizePolicy = QtWidgets.QSizePolicy(QtWidgets.QSizePolicy.Fixed, QtWidgets.QSizePolicy.Fixed)
        sizePolicy.setHorizontalStretch(0)
        sizePolicy.setVerticalStretch(0)
        self.Stag.setSizePolicy(sizePolicy)
        self.Stag.setMaximumSize(QtCore.QSize(50, 16777215))
        self.Stag.setObjectName("Stag")
        self.gridLayout_2.addWidget(self.Stag, 1, 4, 1, 1)
```

Error (1):

TypeError: setupUi() missing 1 required positional argument: 'VlS'

I understand the error is from the 2nd line in first block of code,that it doesn't have .setupUi(VlS). However, when I do this it gives me another error because i'm referring to the module itself.

AttributeError: module 'VlS' has no attribute 'setObjectName'

Is there another way of accessing variables or have I just butchered my code?

Comment: When you designed your class in Qt Designer, what template did you use?

Comment: I used Main window